# Cannot compile Apache 2.0.63 on Windows

Tags: c++, windows, apache, compiler-errors

I'm having issues compiling Apache 2.0.63 on Windows.

So far:

- zlib is compile
- as is openssl-0.9.8za

Here is the output of nmake:

```
C:\httpd>nmake -f Makefile.win installr

Microsoft (R) Program Maintenance Utility Version 10.00.40219.01
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.


INSTDIR    = \Apache2
SERVERNAME = localhost
PORT       = 80
SSLPORT    = 443

To change these options use 'nmake -f Makefile.win [option=value]'
Example: nmake -f Makefile.win PORT=8080


Building Win32 Release targets (R suffixes)
'msdev' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: 'msdev' : return code '0x1'
Stop.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0
\VC\BIN\nmake.exe"' : return code '0x2'
Stop.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 'msdev' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Apache 2.0 can only be built with VC++ 6.0 (Visual Studio 6.0), I don't think it can be built under any modern version of VS.NET. VC++ 6.0 was released in 1998 (if I remember correctly).

While you can no longer get this version from Microsoft, you might be able to find a ISO image/file for the CD on some of the less legitimate "downloads" sites. You'll need to run it on Windows XP in a VM, as there are issues with it installing on Windows 7.

Comment: Indeed! After trial and error, I was able to compile it using VS2008 Express.